# Почему метод не проходит тест на платформе Stepik, но Idea проходит?

Tags: java

Проблема такая:
Решаю задачу на Stepik.
В Idea метод запускается корректно, проблем и ошибок нет.
На Stepik выдает ошибку:
"Ваш ответ не прошел тест!
Неожиданное исключение: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index -1,length 0"
Не понимаю, как так, если в Idea все ок?
Может, решение все-таки неверное? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Условие задачи:
Напишите метод printOddNumbers, который принимает массив и выводит в консоль только нечетные числа из него, через запятую.
Конец вывода должен перевести курсор на новую строку.

Решение:

```
    public class Test{
    /* Были разные варианты убрать запятую, но Stepik не пропускает ни одно решение.
    1 вариант: sb.deleteCharAt((sb.length() - 1));
    2 вариант: delete(sb.length() - 1, sb.length());
    3 вариант: sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(","));
     */
    public static void printOddNumbers(int[] arr) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(arr.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
                sb.append(arr[i] + ",");
            }
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(","));
        System.out.println(sb);
        System.out.println();
    }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {9, 5, 6, 7, 34, 3, 8, 13};
        printOddNumbers(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я уверен [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1011988/Вывод-нечётных-элементов-массива-через-запятую) вы найдете ответ на свой вопрос. Там просто нереально его не найти.

Comment: Спасибо вам, посмотрю!

Comment: посмотрите, что будет, если передать пустой массив или массив только с чётными числами в вашу функцию

Comment: кстати если конкретно по вашей проблеме, то например если в массиве не будет ни одного нечетного числа или если массив будет пустой, то вы попытаетесь обрезать пустой `sb`. А так же последний `println` я думаю лишний, т.к. перед ним есть один, который переместит указатель на новую строчку.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение!

Comment: Мало ли что у этих онлайн ide на уме.

Comment: это точно. онлайн ИДЕ это зло. Задачка уже решена, все ок.