# Как вывести числа чтобы каждая строка вывода оканчивалась числом, а не пробелом

Tags: java, алгоритм

Failed test #1 of 4. Wrong answer

This is a sample test from the problem statement!

Test input:
1 2 3

Correct output:
1 1 1 1
4 8 16 32
9 27 81 243

Your code output:
1111
481632
92781243

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(inp.hasNext()) {
            int num = inp.nextInt();
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++)
                System.out.print((int)Math.pow(num, i));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема заключается в том что при выводе в конце каждой строки пробел.
Необходимо что бы строка заканчивалась числом а не пробелом.

Comment: Другими словами, вам нужно вывести несколько чисел с разделителем. [Вот 25 вариантов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011997/340492) того, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Этот метод возвращает копию вызывающей символьной строки, из которой
удалены все начальные и конечные пробелы. Он имеет следующую общую форму:
String trim ()